# Google maps api v3 map not displaying completly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the [jquery-ui-map](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) plugin in order to add a map to my application.

The problem is that when I load the map it is loaded only half way (see PS below).

(I discovered that if I open the Chrome Developer tool it is loading the map completely).

This is how I create the map:

```
HTML:
<div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>

JavaScript:
$(window).load(function() {
    var mainNode = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    var height = $(window).height() - $("#headerDiv").height() - $("#footerDiv").height();
    var width = window.screen.width;
    mainNode.style.height = height + "px";
    mainNode.style.width = width + "px";
});

$(function() {   
    //Create map and zoom to corrent position
    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) {
        zoomToCurrentPosition();                                                                                                                                                                                   
    });
});

function zoomToCurrentPosition() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            if (currentPositionMarker !== undefined) {
                currentPositionMarker.setMap(null);
            }

            currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position': clientPosition,
                'bounds': true
            });

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', currentPositionMarker);

            $('#map_canvas').gmap({
                'center': clientPosition,
                'zoom': 7
            });

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').panTo(clientPosition);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your "map_canvas_2" div doesn't have a height.

Comment: Sorry, I have this function that will add the height according to the screen height: 
$(window).load(function() {
    var mainNode = document.getElementById("map_canvas_2");
    var height = $(window).height() - $("#headerDiv").height() - $("#footerDiv").height();
    var width = window.screen.width;
    mainNode.style.height = height + "px";
    mainNode.style.width = width + "px";
});

Comment: I updated the question and added the HTML code that I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that initializes the map will be executed  on `DOMReady`, but the function that sets the height will be executed `onload`(what happens **after** DOMReady).

At the moment where you initialize the map the size of `#map_canvas` isn's set yet.

Execute the function that initializes the  map after setting the height.

Comment: Great, it worked, I jest changed the
$(window).load(function()) to $(function())